# Mapping of resources not working for different URLs in spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mapping

I have dispatcher-servlet as

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/"></mvc:resources>
<mvc:resources mapping="/fonts/**" location="/fonts/"></mvc:resources>
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/"></mvc:resources>
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/"></mvc:resources>    
<context:component-scan base-package="com.temple.controller"/>
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

This mapping is valid until the url contains "root-url/css". Now when i login through admin in my project the url becomes "root-url/admin/css" and the css used doesn't work showing.

```
The stylesheet http://localhost:8126/hello/admin/css/entypo.css was not loaded because its MIME type, "text/html", is not "text/css".
```

Now my question is how can i solve all this problem by mapping the resources for all the url. I have tried almost all the mapping problem stated in the stackoverflow and yet i yield no result. Can someone explain me about this how can i solve this?

Comment: Show the jsp which has `link href="entypo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Comment: what part should i show?

Answer (score 0):

```
add default servlet mapping in web xml along with springdispatcher like:
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: wait let me try this

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same exception and spent bit of time exploring various solutions. The dispatcher servlet is the one controlling the incoming requests. The above mapping should be configured in web.xml with <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/, "etcccc" />. So, when request for any js or css comes in, the dispatcher servlet will receive and will map it based on the resource mapping.